# When computer turns on: keyboard/mouse/monitor don't work?

Tags: windows-7, boot, keyboard, display, mouse

the computer is barely good,at least i think..features

- Intel core 2
- 4 GB ram
- Nvidia Radeon 9600 512 mb
- Gigabite motherboad
- (the others i can't remember)..

Used this computer for 3 years with no problem...The problem started one day after while it froze everything, then I shut down with removing the electricity power.  A few hours later, I tried to log in to the computer but nothing moved.  Nor keyboard nor mouse nor monitor worked, I was thinking that should be a delay so I left it some time.  After a minute it turned off without my help around 30 seconds then it turned on automatically, but was the same problem like before and it goes again and again...any suggestions?

If more info/specs required, let me know.

Comment: Nvidia Radeon is one heckuva hybrid  =.=

Answer (score 1):

From what i can gather, you had some kind of problem with your OS. Either its a harddrive failure, OS corruption, or just the Boot menu being corrupted. So, My suggestion to you, to fix this, is to first try reinstalling the operating system, getting it to boot from disc. If that fails, You know its not simply a software problem. If it works, Voila, you lost all your data, and you should have the harddrive checked by someone you trust just to see if it isnt having any problems,but your computer works. My guess would be this is all stemming from a virus. If you put the disk in, and it doesn't end up working, your problem can be either in the processor, the ram, somewhere on the mobo, in the graphics card, in the BIOS, Or the hard drive.

The specs on that system are pretty good for just home use.

Answer (score 0):

If you turned on your PC and nothing Displays, Could be a hardware problem.

Try removing All the RAM, the CMOS Battery and The power Cable from your PC.
Press the Power Button (You need to do this to drain the Motherboard's Capacitors)
Then Plug in the Power cable And Turn it on, Wait a couple few while and See if the Motherboard Beeps.
If it does, Turn it off. Try to Plugin the RAM, and Turn it back on. If It works, Turn it back off and Plug in the CMOS Battery.

Set your CMOS to Fail-Safe Settings if possible.

If it fails, Your Processor might be a problem.
Try Changing if you have a spare one.

All Else fails, Present your Motherboard to the Customer Support.